# How can I find a string using :argdo in vim?

Tags: vim

I tried this:

```
:argdo /pattern
```

However, it just went through all the files very quickly, and did not pause at each location where the string was found.  I just want to iterate over all the locations where a string is found, without replacing.

Comment: Look at `:h vimgrep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has a `:sleep` command that you could use in your command to pause for a few seconds at each match. But a better solution would probably be to use `:vimgrep` or even `:vimgrepadd` to build up a quickfix list including each file, which you can then iterate through on your own with `:cnext`/`:cprev`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find [this screencast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/) very instructive.

A simpler (and less powerful) and relatively obscure (read `:help :ilist`) alternative:

```
:argdo ilist foo
:b <bufname>|<line number>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:vimgrep /pattern/ ##`.

That command will search through your arglist files (the same list that `argdo` uses), load the matches in the `quickfix` list, and then take you to the first match. You can then use `:cn` to move to the next match.

If you use quickfix a lot its well worth installing [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired). That will give you key mappings for quickly navigating the quickfix list (e.g. `]q` instead of `:cn`).

This page gives a good overview on vimgrep and using the quickfix list.
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/